# Запятая перед "либо"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить запятые в предложении:

"Примите оферту(,) либо вернитесь назад и удалите приложение".

Answer (score 7):

Не будем спорить о типе предложения: сложное или простое с однородными сказуемыми. Всем известно, что в науке этот вопрос однозначно не решен. Плюсы и минусы есть у каждой точки зрения. Но если посмотреть на предложение как на простое с  однородными сказуемыми, пунктуация понятна и не требует новых  объяснений.  Союз  *либо* связывает однородные сказуемые: сказуемое *примите*  с парой однородных сказуемых *вернитесь и удалите.*  Все то же правило: при однородных членах перед одиночными союзами И, ИЛИ  запятая не ставится. Союз ЛИБО равнозначен союзу ИЛИ.

Answer (score 2):

"Примите оферту либо вернитесь назад и удалите приложение."- запятая не ставится, если в состав сложносочинённого предл. входят побудительные предложения.

Comment: Согласна, что запятые не нужны. А вот с объяснением... Что,разве совсем не зависит ни от союзов, ни от количества частей?

Comment: Я ответила на вопрос автора, девочке нужно было объяснить наличие знака препинания перед либо, вторая часть (вернитесь назад и удалите приложение) ей было понятно. Насчёт типа предложения Вы неправы, это когда-то спорили, теперь чётко разграничивают односоставные от неполных двусоставных. Вот разбираются типичные ошибки на ЕГЭ:Иду, иду, а до леса никак не дойду. - 3 односоставных.Шёл, шёл, но до леса так и не дошёл - простое неполное двусоставное с однородными сказуемыми.http://ruyaz.ru/sintaksicheskij-razbor-prostogo-predlozheniya/

Comment: Совсем недавно с этим столкнулась.Студентка выполняла контрольную,  охарактеризовала предложение Сижу в зале и переживаю за героя как простое с однородными членами, ей зачеркнули, поставили ошибку. Спрашивает, где ошибка. Я ей объяснила, что это сложносочинённое с двумя односоставными опр.-личными. Поняла, до этого разницы не понимала:опр.-личное предл. мы узнаём по форме главного члена: сказуемое в нём - глагол в  1 и 2 лице ед. и мн. числа изъяв. накл. (в наст. и в буд.времени), и в повелит. наклонении; производитель действия определён.

Comment: Я согласна с Вами. Знаю, что в школе и педагогическом вузе эти предложения считают сложными. Но в  обычных школьных учебниках внимание на таких предложениях не акцентируется. В теме "Односоставные" - рассматриваются простые предложения, в теме "Сложные" в качестве примеров приводятся предложения с безличными частями. Более того, в учебнике Львова (8 класс) в теме "Однородные члены"   (с заданием их подчеркнуть!) даются  такие предложения тоже. При том, как Вы знаете, тема "Сложное предложение" - это 9 класс. Т.е. все подобные трудные  моменты никак не для обычного восьмиклассника.

Comment: А уж что все абсолютно лингвисты согласны - это Вы переборщили. Такое вряд ли. Тогда путаницы, как со Львовым, не было бы. 
А пунктуация все-таки легче объясняется через однородные члены. На мой взгляд.

Comment: Я не вела по Львову, даже учебника не видела. Не могли бы Вы такой пример с однородными привести?

Comment: Я веду 6 класс. Учебника 8 у меня нет. Это коллега подходила с просьбой помочь. При случае поищу.